# Проблема с загрузкой файлов из сети

Tags: android

```
public void StartDownloading()
{
    File file = null;

    for(int i=0; i<FileNames.length; i++) 
    {
         file = new File("/sdcard/Sounds/"+FileNames[i]);
         boolean exists = file.exists();
         if(exists)
         {
             continue;
         }
         else 
         {
             new DownloadFileAsync().execute(Path+FileNames[i],FileNames[i]);               
         }
         file = null;
     }               
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
    switch (id) 
    {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            WaitDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            WaitDialog.setMessage("Downloading files...");
            WaitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            WaitDialog.setCancelable(false);
            WaitDialog.show();
            return WaitDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            File file = new File("/sdcard/Sounds/"+aurl[1]);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte data[] = new byte[4046848];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {}

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) 
    {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);         
    }
}
```

При этом я пытаюсь загрузить 4 файла суммарным весом 2.71 мб, прогресс бар появляется, но обычно быстро пропадает, и файлы остаются загруженные по 5-30кб, иногда даже появляются 1-2 файла тоже по 5-30кб.

Comment: Подозреваю, что в doInBackground() выбрасывается исключение, которое успешно отлавливается catch'ем. Попробуйте в блоке catch сделать вывод исключения в лог и просмотрите его потом.

Comment: Была ошибка  Out of memory on a 10046864-byte allocation. уменьшил. Эффект тотже, кроме как ошибки нету.

Comment: А разрешение на использование INTERNET есть?

Comment: Если он хоть маленькие кусочки грузит. Полюбому есть

Comment: Зачем вы вообще такой гигантский буфер делаете? В этом нет никакого смысла: вы никогда не прочтёте за раз больше, чем размер буффера BufferedInputStream (по умолчанию он 8192). Кроме того, вообще нет смысла делать его таким гигантским: при чтении из сети достаточно 4096 или 8192. Больше нет вообще смысла, это пустая трата ресурсов.

Comment: Ок. Но проблема сейчас не в этом

Comment: Немного не понял вашего ответа, вы предполагаете, что он есть или вы все же в этом уверены?

Comment: Есть конечно

Comment: @Dex: если бы разрашения не было, то файлы получались бы пустыми, либо дело бы не доходило до их создания (упало бы раньше, если бы не было прав).

Comment: Возможно, пасяти не хватает даже на то, чтобы сообщить о её нехватке. Сколько файлов вы пытаетесь запустить на закачку одновременно? Вообще код выглядит правильным, так что других идей не приходит в голову, тем более что вы говорите, что в блоке catch(Exception) ничего не ловится. Вы уверены, что если бы что-то было бы поймано, то вы бы увидели что-то в логах?

Comment: 4 файла, по задумке нада 8 сумарным весом 4+ мб. Опа... Шас немного подебажил, и нашел такую "фишку" диалог(прогресс бар в нашем случае) пропадает когда какая-то часть файлов загружена, а файлы продолжают грузиться, причем до конца(тестировал только раз)...

Comment: И вот ещё: выглядит так, будто вы закрываете и открываете один и тот же лиалог из разных потоков закачки? Как же так?

Comment: Хмм... Ну а как закрыть его по завершению ВСЕХ закачек?

Comment: Вот-вот! Миг назад я как раз подумал о том, что может всё работает на самом деле, а диалог исчезает раньше времени?

Comment: А у меня заработало:)

Comment: Я тестировал только раз, ладно давайте попробуем, какие идеи? Как закрыть диалог по завершению всех закачек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отловить завершение всех загрузок я бы написал что-то типа такого

```
List<File> filesToBeDownloaded = getNonExistFiles();

CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(filesToBeDownloaded.size());
for(File f : filesToBeDownloaded) {
    new FileDownloadTask().execute(f.getName(), latch);
}

new DlAwaitTask().execute(latch);

/// ...

class FileDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, CountDownLatch> {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String fileName, CountDownLatch latch) {
         try {
              // perform download
         } ...
         } finally {
             latch.countDown();
         }
         }
     }
}

class DLAwaitTask exetends AsyncTask<Void, CountDownLatch> {

     //.....
     @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String fileName, CountDownLatch latch) {
         try {
             if(latch.await(MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
                 // download complete.. notify UI
             else
                 // timeout.. show error, etc
         } ....
         } finally {
              // destroy all anyaway
         }
}
```

Разумеется это шаблон, куда вы можете вписать свой код. Кроме того, не мешает копнуть в андроидное API. Возможно найдётся способ запустить эти таски через общий пул потоков и подождать завершения всех задач каким-то более халявным способом.

Comment: Неразобрался со 2 частью

Comment: С DLAwaitTask? Мы запускаем эту таску.. она ждёт latch пока он не сработает (это случится, когда счётчик сойдёт на ноль). Пока он не дойдёт до нуля, поток будет заблокирован в latch.await и будет спать. Он снимется с блокировки, если лотч обнулится, случится таймаут или interrupt. Каждая задача на загрузку заканчивается latch.countDown тем самым сообщая что на одну работающую задачу меньше.

Comment: Помойму слишком заморочено, нам всеголиш нужно определить когда все файлы загружены и убрать с экрана прогресбар

Comment: Всего лишь? У вас N параллельных потоков. Их надо так или иначе синхронизовать. У вас почти нет вариантов. Разве что запускать загрузки в порядке очереди, а не все сразу. К тому же, где вы тут увидели что-то замороченное? Тут добавилась совершенно крошечная таска и добавилось буквально три строки в остальном коде. Вот создавать буффер для простой сетевой операции размером в 4 мегабайта - вот где замороченно ;)

Comment: Хм ок попробывал, есть проблемы...
Incorrect number of arguments for type AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Void, CountDownLatch>

И насчет этого 
List<File> filesToBeDownloaded = getNonExistFiles();

CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(filesToBeDownloaded.size());

Интересно как их получить?
Может быть просто заранее указать известный мне размер?

Comment: Ну я же просто пример написал. Он не абсолютно точен. Хотя, вообще-то у вас нет этого размера как я понимаю.

Comment: Ну файлы то мои...

Comment: Тем не менее закладывать точное число нетехнологично

Comment: Странная проблема, сделал проверку, в finally и далее каждый раз проверяю что бы сумарный вес файлов было около известного мне, с комповского инета все норм, грузит диалог пропадает, а с мобильного! Грузит 2-3 файла, причем кусками, а дальше забивает.

Comment: Я кстати скачал с маркета один прил, он качает архивом. Собственно как анзипить архив с девайса программно?

Comment: Класс анзипа нашел, но проблема осталась всего одна, при анзипе девайс подвисает и выскакивает предл о его заврешнии, подождав минуту конечно все будет разарихвировано, но вот юзер отреагирует не так. Есть какие-то идеи по поводу?

Comment: Так вы как распаковываете? Надо поток запускать